# How to capture only new records from MYSQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I am trying to capture only new records from my MYSQL DB so I can only select those and send them to a S3 bucket as a .csv file. Is there any way or mysql function that holds the timestamp for each record? I am trying to incremental loads from mysql to s3.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no by-default row-level timestamp in MySQL.

One solution would be to create your own, by adding a column to the concerned table(s) and enabling the `default` and `on update` options:

```
alter table mytable add ts timestamp 
    default current_timestamp 
    on update current_timestamp
;
```